# Ошибка при вставке данных: pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: ... relation "sqlite_master" does not exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, sql, postgresql, pandas

Есть вот такой способ записи в БД:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(user=user, password=password, port=config.postgres_port, host=host, database=db)
df.to_sql(name='roads', con=self.conn)
```

В результате чего получаю ошибку:

> pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': relation "sqlite_master" does not exist
> LINE 1: SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?..

Проблема как минимум в том, что Pandas пытается работать с `sqlite`.

Есть ли другие драйверы у Pandas?

Таблица:

```
   CREATE TABLE roads (
        id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        name VARCHAR ( 64 ),
        begin_date TIMESTAMP,
        end_date TIMESTAMP,
        order_ SMALLINT,
        lat REAL,
        lon REAL
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если внимательно прочитать [документацию по `DataFrame.to_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html):

> **con** `sqlalchemy.engine`.(Engine or Connection) or `sqlite3.Connection` Using SQLAlchemy makes it possible to use any DB
> supported by that library. Legacy support is provided for
> sqlite3.Connection objects. The user is responsible for engine
> disposal and connection closure for the SQLAlchemy connectable See
> here.

становится понятно, что Pandas ожидает либо объект типа `sqlalchemy.engine` либо `sqlite3.Connection`. Т.е. при работе с любыми БД кроме SQLite нужно использовать SQL Alchemy в качестве посредника.

Пример:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine


# create SQL Alchemy DB connection
# conn = create_engine('postgresql://user:password@host:port/dbname')
conn = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@host:port/dbname')

df.to_sql('table_name', conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

PS `SQL Alchemy` умеет работать со всеми популярными БД, но скорее всего, для этого придется установить соответствующий драйвер.