# Вставка значений в базу данных из DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Каким обрзом вставить значения в базу данных, если есть ограничения в виде наличия уникальных ключей? При этом не хочется делать на каждую вставку коммит, так как это очень долго. Например, `sqlalchemy` выполняет такую вставку раза в 2 быстрее, чем с коммитами. Предполагается, что используется `DataFrame` из которого читаются данные. Таблица

```
        CREATE TABLE processed_roads (
            road VARCHAR ( 64 ),
            lat_end REAL,
            lon_end REAL,
            segment_index INT,
            unique (segment_index,)
        );
```

Пример со вставкой алхимии:

```
   road_local_df.head(200).to_sql(name='roads', con=self.__conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

`road_local_df` В точности совпадает с таблицей.

В postgresql делаю так:

```
        data = road_local_df
        columns = ','.join(data.columns.tolist())
        for _, row in enumerate(data.iterrows()):
            values = ','.join(fuel_opt.transform_types(row[1].values.tolist()))
            try:
                self._execute_write_query(cursor=cursor, columns=columns, values=values)
                self.__conn.commit()
            except errors.UniqueViolation:
                self.__conn.rollback()
            except Exception as e:
                self.__conn.rollback()
                loguru.logger.error(e)
                raise e
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ дали в другом месте. Это можно решить с помощью `On conflict do nothing`. Пример из [ссылки](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-upsert/):

```
INSERT INTO customers (NAME, email)
VALUES('Microsoft','hotline@microsoft.com') 
ON CONFLICT (name)
DO NOTHING;
```

Для нашего примера можно записать так:

```
INSERT INTO processed_roads (road, lat_end, lon_end, segment_index)
VALUES('123', 1, 2, '333') 
ON CONFLICT (segment_index)
DO NOTHING;
```

Answer (score 2):

Я бы еще посоветовал дополнить [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1187837/211923) советом о том как это правильно делать, используя Pandas:

1. заливаем данные из Pandas DataFrame во **временную** таблицу, перезаписывая ее, если такая уже существует:

```
road_local_df.to_sql(name='tmp_customer', con=self.__conn, 
                     if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

2. запускаем `INSERT INTO customer SELECT * FROM tmp_customer ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING`, используя курсор:

```
cur = engine.raw_connection().cursor()
qry = """
INSERT INTO customer (name, email)
SELECT * from tmp_customer
ON CONFLICT (name)
DO NOTHING
"""
cur.execute(qry)
```

Comment: Зачем тут временная таблица?

Comment: @hedgehogues, чтобы вставлять данные __одним INSERT'ом__, а не в цикле по одной строке. `data.iterrows()` - работает очень медленно

Comment: в этом, плане. Да. Для этого я перевожу всё в строку. И у меня получается огромная длинная строка. Я здесь задавал такой вопрос. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1175420/%d0%a3%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85

Comment: @hedgehogues, не, длинная строка - плохой метод. Может сломаться если будет слишком длинная или нарваться на ограничение по длине SQL в SQLAlchemy. Мой метод лучше :-D

Comment: Понятное дело. Но у нас задача специфичная. У нас тачки по 128 ГБ. Поэтому (=. Ну, Вы поняли. Там очень тяжёлые штуки провариваются. Наверное, можно уменьшить. Но смысла не очень много

Comment: @hedgehogues, я же вам говорю упретесь в ограничение по длине SQL в SQLAlchemy и пусть у вас хоть петабайты памяти ;)

Comment: В Вашем ответе есть нюанс. self.__conn -- только sqlalchemy (=. А мы не хотим плодить либы и хотим пользоваться одним psycopg2. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1183700/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-pandas-io-sql-databaseerror-relation-sqlite-mas

Comment: Опять же, встаёт резонный вопрос,  как из `df` извлечь все данные быстро? Я обычно делаю `df.values`. Быстрее

Comment: @hedgehogues, Pandas официально поддерживает работу с БД __только используя SQLAlchemy как прослойку__. Все остальное от лукавого - т.е. или вы не используете `pd.read_sql()` и `df.to_sql()` и всю работу с БД реализуете сами или используете `SQLAlchemy`. Но если рассуждать как вы, то и Pandas можно самому переписать и "не плодить либы"... :-D

Comment: @hedgehogues, что значит извлечь данные из `df`?? извлечь куда и зачем?

Comment: Ну, странно будет, если в части кода юзать sqlAlchemy, а в части (меньгей) -- нет. Решили избавиться. Лишняя зависимость. Что касается извлечь... то извлечь, чтобы переложить в БД, Очевидно

Comment: @hedgehogues, чтобы переложить в БД придумали метод “df.to_sql()” и в своём ответе я уже показал как им правильно пользоваться если вам нужно пропускать дубликаты. В общем я устал повторять одно и то же - глупо избавляться от библиотек вроде Pandas и SqlAlchemy, которые считаются стандартом “de-facto”